# Linear dependence for $f : v \to W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $f:v \to w$ is linear, suppose that $f(v_1) = w_1,\dots,f(v_n) = w_n$ for some vectors $w_1,\dots,w_n \in w$.

If the set of Ws is dependent, must the set of Vs be dependent?
What if the set of Vs is dependent, must the set of Ws be dependent?

I think if v Is dependent w does not have to be and if w is dependent v has to be. Am I right in my thinking?

Comment: Hi new user. Welcome to MSE! You might want use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Comment: The answer: No and Yes.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane would you mind giving the reasoning for each. I want to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the first question the answer is No: take for example the $(v_i)$ is a basis and $f$ is the zero linear transformation.

More than that, we know that a linear transformation is entirely determined by given the image of a basis, so if $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is **any** set of vector and $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ is a basis then we define a *unique* linear transformation $f$ by *for example*
$$f(v_k)=w_k,\quad \forall k$$

- The second question: Yes: if $(v_i)$ is linearly dependent then WLOG assume that
  $$v_1=\sum_{k=2}^n \alpha_kv_k$$
  and then
  $$w_1=f(v_1)=\sum_{k=2}^n \alpha_kf(v_k)=\sum_{k=2}^n \alpha_kw_k$$
  which means that $(w_i)$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are.

Let $w_1, \dots, w_n$ linear independent, ie. $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i w_i = 0 \Rightarrow a_i = 0 \forall i$. Then use the linearity of $f$ and you get your result.

$V = W = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \equiv 0$ is a counter example for the other direction.